# Specific node in XML file use VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I want to replace data in a XML file using VBA. The XML data looks like this:

```xml
<MarkGrades>
  <Grade MarkGrade="0" Label="3OP" TestBins="1,-1">0</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="2" Label="GOOD" TestBins="2">2</Grade <Grade>           
  <Grade MarkGrade="4" Label="FU" TestBins="31,3135,3136,3312,">4</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="3" Label="PA" TestBins="4016,4022,4029">3</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="5" Label="OS" TestBins="12,13,20012,20013">5</Grade>
</MarkGrades>
```

I want to replace data in node `TestBins`. If `MarkGrade="4"` or `Label="FU"` then replace data in `TestBins` from `"2"` to `"something"`. But I can't seem to figure out how to specify that:

```vb
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Dim isLoaded As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim filePath As Variant
filePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Splitter\test.xml"
isLoaded = doc.Load(filePath)
i = 0

If isLoaded Then
    Dim Grade  As msxml2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set Grade = doc.getElementsByTagName("Grade")

    Dim attr As msxml2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim node As msxml2.IXMLDOMElement
    For Each node In Grade
        For Each attr In node.Attributes
        If attr.Name = "TestBins" Then
            i = i + 1
            If i = 3 Then
                attr.Value = SplitterMark.TextBox3.Value
            ElseIf i = 4 Then
                attr.Value = SplitterMark.TextBox4.Value
            ElseIf i = 5 Then
                attr.Value = SplitterMark.TextBox5.Value

            End If
        End If
        Next attr
    Next node
```

I tried to count if found `TestBins` count +1

That is working good. But can use with only this file because other file it is not common. like this:

```xml
<MarkGrades>
  <Grade MarkGrade="5" Label="OS" TestBins="12,13,20012,20013">5</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="0" Label="3OP" TestBins="1,-1">0</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="4" Label="FU" TestBins="31,3135,3136,3312,">4</Grade>
  <Grade MarkGrade="2" Label="GOOD" TestBins="2">2</Grade <Grade>           
  <Grade MarkGrade="3" Label="PA" TestBins="4016,4022,4029">3</Grade>     
</MarkGrades>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can access the attributes of interest directly by name, instead of looping over them.  E.g. `TestBins = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text`  You can then use those values to determine how to handle each `node`

Comment: Do they always appear together and populated i.e. MarkGrade="4" Label="FU"  such that you really only need to test for one?

Comment: I need to replace the data in TestBins if MarkGrade="4" or Label="FU".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xpath to identify the appropriate nodes and `setAttribute` for the value setting. You need to correct your xml though.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Dim elem As Object

    For Each elem In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Grade[@MarkGrade='4' or @Label='FU' and @TestBins]")
        elem.setAttribute "TestBins", "Banana"
    Next

    Debug.Print xmlDoc.XML
End Sub
```

---

**Corrected xml line:**

```
<Grade MarkGrade="2" Label="GOOD" TestBins="2">2</Grade>
```